# Why does firebase performance use the window object?

Tags: firebase, server-side-rendering, firebase-performance

I have a server side rendered web app made with vue.js and nuxt.js. I'm currently trying to implement firebase performance but it seems like the packages uses the `window` object. Because there is no `window` object on the server I would have to call `firebase.performance()` on the client.

My question is, why does firebase performance use the `window` object? Without knowing how the library works I don't really see why it needs access to the dom. Also as far as I know it also tracks page loading times which would make no sense for me when I only initialize it on the client.

Or did I understood it wrong and performance is only meant to be run on a client and not meant to also measure page loads?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Performance Monitoring for web is only intended to run on browser clients.  It's the same for Android and iOS - made for clients only.  The idea is to measure your app's performance on the user's device, since that data is difficult to measure otherwise.  If you want to measure the performance of server side code, there are other tools for that, but Firebase doesn't provide them.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense!